# why does server with play framework shutdown abnormally

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Our server backend is with play framework. During developing it seems everything is OK until we deploy it to production environment.

In production environment, the server just shutdown without any errors/warnings in logs. The last logs is like below:

> 2016-03-16 10:15:44,866 - [INFO] - from application in
>   ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1 ReactiveMongoApi stopping... 2016-03-16
>   10:15:44,903 - [INFO] - from application in ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3
>   ReactiveMongoApi connections stopped. [Success(Closed)] 2016-03-16
>   10:15:44,958 - [INFO] - from
>   play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider in
>   ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1 Shutdown application default Akka system:
>   application

My question is: in which case would play shutdown itself? Why there is no error messages? Where should I check into first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the production app being hosted on an Amazon AWS or other cloud solution like Heroku? Depending on what "tier" of service you have, the node hosting your app may be being "cycled". I know I've seen this on my free-tier Heroku apps, where "dynos" have to [shut down for 6 hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping) per day.

Comment: Just in case someone might encounter the same problem, I found what caused the issue in our case.

From the system log, we found out that the play will be shutdown any time SSH session is closed. So we use nohup to start the server to resolve the problem.

Details of the problem: before, we SSH to our server and start play server with & to put it to background. But actually it still bounds with the shell thus eventually at some random time when the SSH session closes, the play server will shutdown immediately.